# Validate PL/SQL without running it?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am generating a lot of scripts, I would like to know if they are valid before starting to run them.
I know you can do this from TOAD, etc. But I want to know if there is a way to do it with PL/SQL.

What I want is to validate the SQL is valid before execute it. I have all kind of statements, many of them are DDL and Inserts.

Is there a command in PL/SQL that provides syntax checking?

Comment: `dbms_sql.parse()` can do that to a certain extent: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68277

Comment: Do you mean running, like in executing, or creating them in the database?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I mean both. I will add a note to my question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right it would be useful to a certain extent, but It won't be useful for the DDL statements. Thanks though, I didn't know about that package.

Comment: This is usually taken care during development itself. Developers use dvms_output to first validate the dynamic queries in test environment. Then the dbms_output is removed before moving into production.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I understand that, however validating without running the queries can be error prone, and also very complicated if you have a thousand scripts.

Comment: So you mean to say there was no UNIT testing done? Developers didn't care to write their unit test cases?

Comment: @LalitKumarB I am saying I want a way to validate the syntax of a lot of scripts using PL/SQL for development purposes.